# Make text appear with green-white background

Tags: html, css, colors, background-image

I have a football field, where I am going to allow the user to drag the player where he wants in the field. However, I can't find a way to make the name of the player clear, when on the field, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/).

My last attempt is this:

```
<p style="color: #3D59AB;">
    Philio
</p>
```

taken from [here](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm).

How to make the text appear nicely?

Comment: can't u make the text inside a bubble or something to make it more visible

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but consider that there we be at total 10 players, so I want to save as much space as possible.

Comment: then just choose a color that is best visible on a green background...try a few..i guess yellow should do

Comment: Yes it is visible now @Rash, but it's not nice. Maybe you can share an example with a little bubble?

Comment: Plain white I'd say works best

Comment: just wrap the name around a div..give div some width and height...then do the background of the div as white and name as any color.

Comment: But @BenMansley, it won;t be visible when the player is placed in the lines of the field.

Comment: something like this would work for u? http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/1/

Comment: That's exactly what I had before posting @Rash, with black color. In my eye, it doesn't feel pretty, I do not know if you agree.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/3/ ? you can play around with the values and the colors

Comment: well how about instead of div you put an image of a player...and when you hover on that player it gives their name?

Comment: That's what I tried at first, but I couldn't make the images seem nice when the where getting smaller.

Comment: dont put an image..instead use glyphicon or font-awesome..those are images made purely from css and they wont get distorted when resized

Comment: You could use a semi-opaque background color, which would probably work best with a little bit of padding. As example: `style='display: inline-block; padding: 2px;color: white; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)'`. 

For an rgba value, you specify the red, green and blue hues which make up the color (each in the range 0-255, there are many online color pickers you can use to find the color you want), and then opacity in the range 0-1 where 0 is fully transparent, and 1 is fully opaque.

Comment: @Rash that's very interested, since that's what I wanted to have from the start. Nodehead, that seems nice, are you going to post an answer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/6/?

Comment: Wow @BenMansley I would surely accept this as an answer, bravo!

Comment: Thanks. Will answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above, try wrapping the text in a `<span>` and styling that. A border helps to distinguish it from the pitch, and it looks a bit cleaner when curved.

Something like:

HTML:

```
 <p>
     <span class="player">Philio</span>
 </p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://p1.pichost.me/i/17/1401060.jpg");
}

p {
    padding: 120px;
}

.player {
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(40, 180, 40, 0.8);
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50px;  // setting a border radius larger than 1/2 the height causes a rounded edge.
}
```

Of course you can play around with the values and colors, good luck :)

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/6/

Comment: Thanks, to be honest my real situation is this: http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/12/, however the border gets big, why? :/

Comment: Because it's a `<div>`, it has `display:block` which means it takes up 100%  of the parent. Add a `display: inline-block` rule and it looks fine :)

Comment: Here it is working with a couple of different sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/15/ Hooray for Greek names!

Comment: Haha, we have several players in the style of that name. Btw, nice top answer too.

Comment: Firefox issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680682/image-gets-moved-on-drag

Answer (score 1):

You can use css and do the following with a text shadow.

```
p {
    padding: 120px;
    color: #EEEE00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2twvek/16/)