# Image gets moved on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In Chrome it works fine, but not in Firefox, as you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk58tu36/1/). The problem is that the picture next to player gets moved when the player is dragged.

Here is the CSS:

```
.player {
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(40, 180, 40, 0.8);
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How to make it work in Firefox too?

---

Bonus question: In order to keep the picture a little separate from the player (in both browsers), I use a whitespace after the player. It would be nice if I could that with CSS only.

Comment: I just tried with FF 40.0.3 ... works like a charm ... with which version did you test it?

Comment: works perfect in FF here || as for the spacing try `.player>span:first-of-type{
    padding-right:10px
}` - http://jsfiddle.net/pk58tu36/3/

Comment: I get this issue on FF 40.0.3 when running your fiddle as well.  Is probably related to an older bug within jqueryUI in that it sets an explicit width/height on the element when performing drag.  This bug seems to have re-appeared in the last few versions.
Try using jqUI version 1.11.1, fixed the issue in my tests

Comment: @BadToken, your comment should me an answer! maioman thanks! Same version LGSon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this issue on FF 40.0.3 when running your fiddle as well. Is probably related to an [older bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10725) within jqueryUI in that it sets an explicit width/height on the element when performing drag. This bug seems to have re-appeared in the last few versions. Try using jQueryUI version 1.11.1.

Answer (score 2):

To separate text/image I removed the extra span around img tag (can't see what good that extra span does) and added margin to the alignPic class.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pk58tu36/2/

```
.alignPic {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```